# Refactoring and simplifying for loops to be more "Swifty"

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I have a fairly simple for-loop that I would like to refactor to be more "Swifty".  I'm sure this is do-able with some kind of map or other cool mechanism.  If it's not too much to ask, it would be beneficial of me to hear a thought-process behind refactoring/creating these, as it's one area of Swift that I just can't seem to wrap my head around very well (I'm stuck on an old-school for-loop mindset!).

The loop goes through an array of dictionaries to find the one we need (based on a refKey==refVal), then it simply pulls a different value needed from that particular dictionary based on "keyForWhatWeWant":

```
for currentDictionary in dictionaries where currentDictionary["refKey"] == "refVal" {
    if let valueWeWant = currentDictionary["keyForWhatWeWant"] {
        return valueWeWant
    }
}
```

I do want it to pass through this code and move on if it does not find the value, though, FYI.

Comment: Can many dictionaries have "refKey" == "refVal" as your code implies?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson nope, in my case, only one dictionary will have it.  And even if multiple did, we can just assume to grab the first one it matches there.

Comment: An array of dictionaries seems like something that should be refactored first.

Comment: @svguerin3 I agree with Sulthan you should structure your data

Comment: @Paulw11 the question looks like a Generic Best Practice question to me and so is likely to be off-topic on Code Review. Please read [Code Review's help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) before recomending Code Review, or worse closing because Code Review exists.

Comment: I don't think it is asking for generic best practice. It is asking for specific, Swift, refactoring of working code, however I accept your feedback. The question is arguably off-topic for stack overflow too, since any answers will likely be opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Swift collection method first where predicate to find the dictionaries that fit your criteria and then get its key "keyForWhatWeWant". IMO the for loop approach seems cleaner:

```
if let valueWeWant = dictionaries.first(where: { 
    $0["refKey"] == "refVal" && $0["keyForWhatWeWant"] != nil 
})?["keyForWhatWeWant"] {
    print("valueWeWant:", valueWeWant)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the well-thought answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for, and I see what you mean that the for-loop may actually be cleaner and more readable.  This at least gets a conversation going.  Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome